# Unable to deploy minimal static site on google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, static

I am trying to serve static site on app engine and I am pretty unsuccessful with deployment. I followed the tutorial here https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/getting-started/hosting-a-static-website . The only update is that I do specify the service name.

The app is pretty minimal

app.yaml

```
runtime: python27
service: swdocs
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /
   static_files: www/index.html
   upload: www/index.html
   secure: always

- url: /(.*)
static_files: www/\1
upload: www/(.*)
```

The file tree is

```
.
├── app.yaml
└── www
    └── index.html
```

When I deploy it and go to the page

```
gcloud app deploy
gcloud app browse
```

The app is not reachable. Out of ~10 deploys one actually works if I go to the version url not the service url (and only in Chrome, not safari). I am not deploying to my own domain. I am using the appspot one.

Anybody has an idea what I might be doing wrong or how to debug?

Comment: Did you have any previous service deployed before trying to deploy `swdocs`? If you didn't, the 1st deploy has to be done to the `default` service. If that's not the case, having more information on what error are you seeing, logs of the errors occurring and even providing `gcloud app deploy --verbosity=debug` will be good in order to be able to help further.

Comment: Hey @bhito. This is not the first service. This morning all the services (all old versions) and new versions I deploy with the exactly same code work as expected. Weird probably some glitch on the google side? Thanks for help anyway.